# Is there a payment gateway that allows splitting the funds and sending it to multiple bank accounts

Tags: stripe-payments, payment-gateway, payment, square

I'm building an application that will use a payment gateway such as square or stripe. After I have successfully transferred the funds to my gateway account I need to split the money into shares such as 20% commission fee and 80% to the agency that provides the actual service. After I have split the money I need to send it to their individual bank accounts.
The question is:

Can something like this be done using standard payment gateways and if it cannot be done, is there any other options to implement this?

Comment: i'm sure that there is a "send money" section at least on stripe

Comment: Payment processors do one thing - process a customer payment into a single account. It's then up to you to run your own financials and distribute from that account as required.